# Create the stored procedure to compare records and update system generated record

Tags: sql-server-2014-express

I want help for this: I have 4 vehicle records from different users:

```
    vehicle_id      vehicle_name    vehicle_number      date_update
usr1    10           My Ferrari      1000                   NULL
usr2    11           My Ferrari      1000                   NULL
usr3    12           My Ferrari      1000                   NULL    
usr4    13           My Ferrari      1001                   NULL
```

On this records I want common record so, I have applied Group By and create separate record as my system generated record

```
      vehicle_id        vehicle_name    vehicle_number      date_update
sys         14           My Ferrari      1000                   NULL
```

Now here is my condition:

Condition 1: **3 records are the same and one is different**

If any user updates his own record, then system or script also re-calculate or compare all four records and update the column in my sys record

I am also setting record updated date.

E.g

```
      vehicle_id        vehicle_name    vehicle_number      date_update
usr1        10           My Ferrari      1000                   NULL
usr2        11           My Ferrari      1001                   09/03/2018  
usr3        12           My Ferrari      1001                   09/03/2018
usr4        13           My Ferrari      1001                   NULL
```

So my sys record also get updated

```
        vehicle_id      vehicle_name    vehicle_number      date_update
sys         14           My Ferrari      1001                   09/03/2018
```

Condition 2: **Every 2 records having same value on this condition need to get latest UPDATED record**

E.g

```
     vehicle_id         vehicle_name    vehicle_number      date_update
usr1        10           My Ferrari      1002                   09/03/2018 8:55 AM
usr2        11           My Ferrari      1001                   09/03/2018 7:55 AM
usr3        12           My Ferrari      1001                   09/03/2018 7:30 AM
usr4        13           My Ferrari      1002                   09/03/2018 8:57 AM
```

So my sys record also get updated

```
     vehicle_id         vehicle_name    vehicle_number      date_update
sys         14           My Ferrari      1002                   09/03/2018
```

Condition 3: **Every record contain different records on this condition need to get latest UPDATED record**

E.g

```
       vehicle_id       vehicle_name    vehicle_number        date_update
usr1        10           My Ferrari      1001                   09/03/2018 8:55 AM
usr2        11           My Ferrari      1003                   09/03/2018 7:55 AM
usr3        12           My Ferrari      1004                   09/03/2018 7:30 AM
usr4        13           My Ferrari      1005                   09/03/2018 8:57 AM
```

So my sys record also get updated

```
     vehicle_id         vehicle_name    vehicle_number      date_update
sys         14           My Ferrari      1005                   09/03/2018
```

So what is the best way to handle all three conditions in a stored procedure and update my Sys record accordingly?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

To summarize ur problem..in all three condition sys record is always that record that is updated by user lately.

Sol: use insert and update trigger.
SP wont solve ur problem here.

Into that trigger script use order by date modified as key column to get latest vaule with dense_rank to evalute latest record for more than one value.

Hope this will solve ur problem